# Window not defined in Background component that changes color on mouseover in Next.js-TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have this Background component, which contains a function that contains an svg. On `mouseover`, the bacground is supposed to change color. This works. The issue now, is that in production, I am using vercel to host, the error i get is `ReferenceError: window is not defined`. I need help as I need to host this project soonest.

I looked at codes on this platform `stackoverflow`, and the solutions I have been seeing is for the usage of `next/link` in linking. I tried wrapping my code in an if statement that says `if (typeof window !== 'undefined')`. This still didn't solve the issue as it still gave me the same error in production. I also tried defining `windows` in my `types`, but I still got the same output. I also tried to make the imports to the respective components affected with `next/dynamic` still to no avail.

`Background.tsx`

```
"use client"

import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import './Background.scss'

type BgTypes ={
    isDarkMode: any
}

export default function Background({isDarkMode}: BgTypes) {
    const [strokeColor, setStrokeColor] = useState('')
    const [intensity, setIntensity] = useState(0)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        // Set stroke color based on the theme (dark or light)
        const newStrokeColor = isDarkMode ? '#432962' : '#FFB17A';
        setStrokeColor(newStrokeColor);
    }, [isDarkMode]);

    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            // Update intensity based on mouse movement
            const handleMouseMove = (event: MouseEvent) => {
                const { clientX, clientY } = event;
                const intensityX = (clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
                const intensityY = (clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 - 1;
                const totalIntensity = Math.sqrt(intensityX ** 2 + intensityY ** 2);
                setIntensity(totalIntensity);
            };

            window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);

            return () => {
                window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
            };
        }
    }, []);

    const interpolatedColor = interpolateColor(intensity);


    return(
        <div id="bg">
            <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1422 800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <g fill="none" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke={interpolatedColor} stroke-linejoin="round">
                <polygon points="1422 0 1244.2 0 1244.2 100"/>
                <polygon points="1066.5 0 1244.2 100 1066.5 100"/>
                <polygon points="1244.2 100 1066.5 200 1244.2 200"/>
                <polygon points="1422 200 1244.2 200 1244.2 100"/>
                <polygon points="1066.5 0 1066.5 100 888.75 0"/>
                <polygon points="888.75 0 711 0 711 100"/>
                <polygon points="888.75 200 711 200 711 100"/>
                <polygon points="888.75 200 1066.5 100 1066.5 200"/>
                <polygon points="1066.5 200 888.75 200 888.75 300"/>
                <polygon points="888.75 250 799.88 250 888.75 200"/>
                <polygon points="799.88 250 799.88 200 711 200"/>
                <polygon points="711 250 711 300 799.88 250"/>
                <polygon points="888.75 300 888.75 250 799.88 250"/>
                <polygon points="888.75 325 844.31 325 888.75 300"/>
                <polygon points="844.31 325 799.88 325 799.88 300"/>
                <polygon points="844.31 325 799.88 350 799.88 325"/>
                <polygon points="888.75 350 844.31 350 844.31 325"/>
                <polygon points="799.88 300 711 300 799.88 350"/>
                <polygon points="711 400 799.88 400 799.88 350"/>
                <polygon points="888.75 375 888.75 350 844.31 375"/>
                <polygon points="799.88 350 844.31 350 844.31 375"/>
                <polygon points="844.31 400 844.31 375 799.88 400"/>
                <polygon points="888.75 400 844.31 375 844.31 400"/>
                <polygon points="977.62 350 1066.5 300 1066.5 350"/>
                <polygon points="977.62 350 977.62 300 888.75 350"/>
                <polygon points="977.62 400 888.75 350 977.62 350"/>
                <polygon points="1066.5 400 977.62 350 1066.5 350"/>
                <polygon points="1422 300 1422 200 1244.2 300"/>
                <polygon points="1244.2 250 1155.4 250 1155.4 200"/>
                <polygon points="1066.5 250 1155.4 200 1155.4 250"/>
                <polygon points="1155.4 300 1155.4 250 1066.5 300"/>
                <polygon points="1244.2 250 1155.4 250 1155.4 300"/>
                <polygon points="1244.2 300 1244.2 400 1066.5 300"/>
                <polygon points="1422 400 1422 300 1244.2 400"/>
                <polygon points="711 100 533.25 0 711 0"/>
                <polygon points="533.25 100 355.5 0 355.5 100"/>
                <polygon points="533.25 150 444.38 150 533.25 100"/>
                <polygon points="444.38 100 444.38 150 355.5 100"/>
                <polygon points="444.38 150 355.5 200 444.38 200"/>
                <polygon points="444.38 150 533.25 150 533.25 200"/>
                <polygon points="711 100 533.25 100 533.25 200"/>
                <polygon points="355.5 100 177.75 100 355.5 0"/>
                <polygon points="177.75 0 0 0 0 100"/>
                <polygon points="177.75 100 88.875 100 177.75 150"/>
                <polygon points="88.875 150 0 150 88.875 100"/>
                <polygon points="88.875 150 88.875 200 0 150"/>
                <polygon points="177.75 150 88.875 200 177.75 200"/>
                <polygon points="266.62 100 355.5 150 266.62 150"/>
                <polygon points="177.75 100 266.62 150 177.75 150"/>
                <polygon points="177.75 150 266.62 200 266.62 150"/>
                <polygon points="355.5 200 355.5 150 266.62 200"/>
                <polygon points="177.75 300 177.75 200 355.5 300"/>
                <polygon points="177.75 200 0 200 177.75 300"/>
                <polygon points="0 400 177.75 300 0 300"/>
                <polygon points="355.5 300 355.5 400 177.75 300"/>
                <polygon points="711 200 622.12 200 622.12 250"/>
                <polygon points="622.12 250 622.12 200 533.25 250"/>
                <polygon points="533.25 250 622.12 250 533.25 300"/>
                <polygon points="711 300 622.12 250 622.12 300"/>
                <polygon points="444.38 250 444.38 200 533.25 250"/>
                <polygon points="444.38 200 444.38 250 355.5 250"/>
                <polygon points="444.38 250 444.38 300 355.5 250"/>
                <polygon points="444.38 300 533.25 250 444.38 250"/>
                <polygon points="533.25 300 444.38 300 444.38 350"/>
                <polygon points="444.38 350 444.38 300 355.5 300"/>
                <polygon points="355.5 350 444.38 400 444.38 350"/>
                <polygon points="533.25 400 444.38 350 533.25 350"/>
                <polygon points="711 300 711 350 622.12 350"/>
                <polygon points="533.25 350 622.12 300 622.12 350"/>
                <polygon points="533.25 350 622.12 400 533.25 400"/>
                <polygon points="711 350 711 400 622.12 400"/>
                <polygon points="711 400 711 450 622.12 400"/>
                <polygon points="622.12 450 622.12 400 533.25 450"/>
                <polygon points="533.25 450 622.12 500 622.12 450"/>
                <polygon points="711 450 622.12 450 622.12 500"/>
                <polygon points="444.38 450 533.25 400 533.25 450"/>
                <polygon points="355.5 450 444.38 450 444.38 400"/>
                <polygon points="444.38 450 355.5 500 355.5 450"/>
                <polygon points="533.25 450 444.38 500 444.38 450"/>
                <polygon points="533.25 500 533.25 550 444.38 500"/>
                <polygon points="444.38 500 355.5 500 355.5 550"/>
                <polygon points="444.38 550 444.38 600 355.5 600"/>
                <polygon points="533.25 600 533.25 550 444.38 600"/>
                <polygon points="711 600 711 500 533.25 500"/>
                <polygon points="177.75 400 355.5 500 177.75 500"/>
                <polygon points="0 500 177.75 500 177.75 400"/>
                <polygon points="177.75 600 0 500 0 600"/>
                <polygon points="177.75 500 355.5 600 177.75 600"/>
                <polygon points="355.5 600 177.75 700 177.75 600"/>
                <polygon points="177.75 700 0 600 0 700"/>
                <polygon points="0 800 177.75 800 0 700"/>
                <polygon points="177.75 700 355.5 800 177.75 800"/>
                <polygon points="711 600 711 650 622.12 600"/>
                <polygon points="622.12 650 622.12 600 533.25 600"/>
                <polygon points="533.25 700 622.12 650 622.12 700"/>
                <polygon points="711 700 622.12 650 711 650"/>
                <polygon points="355.5 600 533.25 700 355.5 700"/>
                <polygon points="533.25 800 533.25 700 355.5 800"/>
                <polygon points="711 700 533.25 700 533.25 800"/>
                <polygon points="1422 500 1244.2 400 1422 400"/>
                <polygon points="1155.4 450 1244.2 400 1244.2 450"/>
                <polygon points="1155.4 400 1155.4 450 1066.5 450"/>
                <polygon points="1155.4 500 1066.5 500 1066.5 450"/>
                <polygon points="1155.4 500 1244.2 450 1155.4 450"/>
                <polygon points="1244.2 600 1066.5 500 1066.5 600"/>
                <polygon points="1244.2 600 1422 500 1422 600"/>
                <polygon points="1066.5 400 1066.5 450 977.62 450"/>
                <polygon points="977.62 450 888.75 450 977.62 400"/>
                <polygon points="977.62 450 977.62 500 888.75 500"/>
                <polygon points="1066.5 450 1066.5 500 977.62 500"/>
                <polygon points="888.75 400 799.88 400 799.88 450"/>
                <polygon points="799.88 450 799.88 400 711 450"/>
                <polygon points="799.88 500 799.88 450 711 450"/>
                <polygon points="799.88 500 888.75 450 888.75 500"/>
                <polygon points="888.75 500 888.75 550 799.88 550"/>
                <polygon points="799.88 500 711 550 711 500"/>
                <polygon points="799.88 600 799.88 550 711 600"/>
                <polygon points="888.75 550 888.75 600 799.88 600"/>
                <polygon points="977.62 500 1066.5 500 1066.5 550"/>
                <polygon points="888.75 500 977.62 550 977.62 500"/>
                <polygon points="977.62 550 977.62 600 888.75 550"/>
                <polygon points="1066.5 600 977.62 600 1066.5 550"/>
                <polygon points="888.75 600 1066.5 600 1066.5 700"/>
                <polygon points="888.75 600 711 600 711 700"/>
                <polygon points="711 800 888.75 700 711 700"/>
                <polygon points="888.75 800 1066.5 700 888.75 700"/>
                <polygon points="1422 700 1244.2 600 1244.2 700"/>
                <polygon points="1244.2 700 1244.2 600 1066.5 700"/>
                <polygon points="1244.2 700 1244.2 800 1066.5 700"/>
                <polygon points="1422 800 1422 700 1244.2 700"/>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    )
}

function interpolateColor(intensity: number): string {
    // Interpolate between two colors based on intensity
    const color1 = '#432962';
    const color2 = '#FFB17A';

    const r = Math.round((1 - intensity) * parseInt(color1.slice(1, 3), 16) + intensity * parseInt(color2.slice(1, 3), 16));
    const g = Math.round((1 - intensity) * parseInt(color1.slice(3, 5), 16) + intensity * parseInt(color2.slice(3, 5), 16));
    const b = Math.round((1 - intensity) * parseInt(color1.slice(5, 7), 16) + intensity * parseInt(color2.slice(5, 7), 16));

    return `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
}
```

`page.tsx` for the about page, one of the pages affected. This is to show how I imported it.

```
"use client"

import { useState } from 'react'
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar/Navbar";
import AboutContent from '@/components/AboutContent/AboutContent';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

export default function About() {
    const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = useState(false)
    const Background = dynamic(() => import('@/components/Background/Background'), {
        ssr: false
    })

    return(
        <div id="about">
            {/* <NextSeo
                title='About Me'
            /> */}

            <Navbar isDarkMode={isDarkMode} setIsDarkMode={setIsDarkMode} />
            <Background isDarkMode={isDarkMode}/>
            <AboutContent isDarkMode={isDarkMode} setIsDarkMode={setIsDarkMode} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way you try to load your component. It needs to be at the top level of the file and not inside the parent component you want to use the lazy/dynamically loaded component in.

As stated in the [Nextjs docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading#examples)

> dynamic() can't be used inside of React rendering as it needs to be marked in the top level of the module for preloading to work, similar to React.lazy

```js
"use client"

import { useState } from 'react'
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar/Navbar";
import AboutContent from '@/components/AboutContent/AboutContent';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

// import here at the top level
const Background = dynamic(() => import('@/components/Background/Background'), {
    ssr: false
})

export default function About() {
    const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = useState(false)

    return(
        <div id="about">
            {/* <NextSeo
                title='About Me'
            /> */}

            <Navbar isDarkMode={isDarkMode} setIsDarkMode={setIsDarkMode} />
            <Background isDarkMode={isDarkMode}/>
            <AboutContent isDarkMode={isDarkMode} setIsDarkMode={setIsDarkMode} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have moved the dynamic import to the top level. I still get the `ReferenceError: window is not defined` error in the production. I literally am still lost. Thank you for this information.

Is this how Vercel does during production? I know it is because of `Next.js` putting this code on the node servers first. I still need clarity